# Jquery Tabs Loading gif

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have my tabs defined as follows -

```
$(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs({
            beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
                var tab = $(ui.tab);

                if (tab.is(":empty")) {
                    tab.append(" <div class='loadinggiftabs' ><img src='./Content/graphics/loading.gif' /></div>")
                }

                alert('before');
            },
            load: function (event, ui) {
                $(ui.tab).find(".loadinggiftabs").remove();
                alert('after');
            }
        });
    });
```

The issue is that the loading gif `loadinggiftabs` never seems to get appended (and, therefore, removed). The alerts do get called. There are no JS errors according to Chrome dev tools. I have also tried to append to the `ui.panel` instead of `ui.tab`

Thank you.

Comment: are you sure your tab is :empty ?

Comment: doesn't `beforeLoad` occur just before `load`, leaving very little time for the loading gif to actually show?

Comment: @roasted Yes I am sure. I confirmed with chrome js debugger.

Comment: @JanDvorak Maybe. I am new to jquery. Do you know a better/proper way how to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Normally, you'd place/show the loading GIF when you start doing something, and remove/hide it when you finish. "when you start doing" is usually "now. Don't wait for anything".

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah that's what I am trying to do but I couldn't find any other event of tab to use. That said I simulated a 3 sec pause in the service tab is calling and still nothing.

Comment: So...I am a tool. This was working all along. `loadinggiftabs` was set to `display:none`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here´s another way to solve that

```
<div id="spinner" style="display:none;"><img src="/Images/loading.gif" /></div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#spinner").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
        $(this).show();
    }).bind("ajaxStop", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    }).bind("ajaxError", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similiar troubles. It took me ages to find something working.
This is my working soloution now.

Notice, it also caches. That if-construct is nescessary to make caching work, otherwise it reloads everthing all the time.

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        cache: true,
        /* Probably won't need this object, it's just to appease jsfiddle */
        ajaxOptions: {},

        beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
            if ($(ui.panel).html()) {
                event.preventDefault()
                return false;
            }
            else {
                ui.panel.html('<div><img src="/Images/loading.gif" /></div>');
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```